# How to fix "ContactPoint must be attached to a parent with a declared type" linting error repored by SDTT

Tags: schema.org

The following template is supposed to represent a Gov Service with a ServicePhone / Contact Point:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "GovernmentService",
  "name": "",
  "serviceType": "",
  "url": "",
  "audience": {
    "@type": "Audience",
    "name": ""
  },
  "availableChannel": {
    "@type": "ServiceChannel",
    "name": "",
    "serviceLocation": {
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "",
        "addressLocality": "",
        "postalCode": ""
      }
    },
    "servicePhone": {
      "@type" : "ContactPoint",
      "telephone" : "",
      "email": "",
      "name": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Which leads to the error message

> "ContactPoint must be attached to a parent with a declared type."

https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

What am I missing?

edit: removing out-of-schema props, add screenshot

[result of SDTT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtA0C.png)

Comment: It is strange that Google reports an error in your markup. Your markup is valid on the JSON-LD Playground https://json-ld.org/playground/. Maybe a Google bug.